# Generate a checksum for this input

Tags: performance, bash, checksum

I am inputting a file of `uniq -c | sort -nr` and I need to

1. take the string from the file,
2. generate a unique id of the string and then
3. Output a pipe separated value of `cksum|$string`

The code below works, but I definitely feel like it could be improved. Perhaps removing the `tr` or not using `xargs` since I can parallelize it anyways.

### Input

```
3671184 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
3195403 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Transfered zip file failed validation
1118052 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: BIP job failed
190220 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
163155 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.xdo.servlet.CreateException
136588 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Atleast One of the Child requests ended in error or Warning
85080 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Could not update entity indexing state for entity with uuid: '{.uuid}' in meta model version with uuid '{.uuid}': method [PUT], host
75707 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Failure during Schedule Item Import job..
69138 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Spawned job for request {.request_id} produced the business error exit code: BIZ_ERROR
57302 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Returning a business error. Do not re-try.
```

### Code

```bash
head uniq.txt | sed -E 's/[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g' | 
    tr '\n' '\0' |
      xargs -0 -n 1 sh -e -c ' echo "${1}" | cksum | cut -d" " -f1 && echo "${1}"' _ |
    tr '\n' '\0' |
      xargs -0 -n 2 printf "%d|%s\n"
```

The switching between `\n` and `\0` is because the line I am feeding to xargs has spaces and new lines in it, and xargs will treat those as token separators.

### Output

```
3839440388|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
1495326131|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Transfered zip file failed validation
126216303|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: BIP job failed
2952592408|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
719205600|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.xdo.servlet.CreateException
437977472|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Atleast One of the Child requests ended in error or Warning
2503345575|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Could not update entity indexing state for entity with uuid: '{.uuid}' in meta model version with uuid '{.uuid}': method [PUT], host
2651334677|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Failure during Schedule Item Import job..
3069376900|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Spawned job for request {.request_id} produced the business error exit code: BIZ_ERROR
3790403139|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Returning a business error. Do not re-try.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Minimize program executions per loop iteration

Executing programs has an overhead, and when doing that in a loop, it quickly becomes noticeable.

For each line in the input, many programs will be executed, namely `sh`, `cksum`, `cut`.

With the given input example, the following produces the same output, executing only `cksum`:

```
head uniq.txt | while read count line; do
  read s _ < <(cksum <<< "$line")
  echo "$s|$line"
done
```

Another strategy could be to generate an output of all the checksums, and then paste that with the original lines:

```
head uniq.txt | sed -E 's/[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g' > lines.txt
paste -d'|' <(while read line; do cksum <<< "$line"; done < lines.txt | cut -f1 -d' ') lines.txt
```

#### No need to convert `\n` to `\0`

It seems the only reason to convert `\n` to `\0` is because the subshell outputs 2 lines for 1 line of input. It would be simpler to make the subshell output a single line, and then you won't need the conversion:

```
head uniq.txt | sed -E 's/[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g' | 
  xargs -d '\n' -n 1 sh -e -c 'echo "$1" | cksum | cut -d" " -f1 && echo "$1"' _ |
  xargs -d '\n' -n 2 printf "%d|%s\n"
```

#### Prefer simpler regexes

If the purpose of `sed -E 's/[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g'` is to remove the numeric prefix of the lines, then it's simpler to write:

```
... | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ //'
```

Comment: `xargs -d` isn't available by default on some systems (like my mac)

Comment: I like the simplification of `sed` because, yes, it is to remove the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
      xargs -0 ...
```

Sorry, you kind of lost me there.

You had a line-oriented input stream going through `head` & `sed`,
and then you switched to NUL delimited? Why?
There are perfectly good reasons for using `xargs -0`,
but this isn't one of them.
Recommend you just delete that aspect.

---

```
    ... | sed -E 's/[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g' | ...
```

Style nit: better to anchor this with `^` caret.

```
    ... | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ (.*)/\1/g' | ...
```

It happens that it doesn't make a difference for your particular input.
But it's a good habit to adopt, so the regex engine
doesn't accidentally do lots of scanning work you weren't expecting.

---

```
... sh -e ...
```

I confess I don't understand exactly what's going on here.
This seems to be `set -e -o pipefail`.
But can `echo` fail?
Or `cksum`?
Really?
Maybe it's just a harmless "extra" flag.

---

> I definitely feel like [the code] could be improved

```
    ... |
    xargs ... -n 1 sh ... -c ... | ... |
    xargs ... -n 2 printf "%d|%s\n"
```

Yes, there's certainly room for improvement.

Sometimes `-n 1` is exactly what the doctor ordered;
it may be necessary for correctness.
If you read N lines and have to spawn N shells
that suggests that maybe we're not quite playing
to the strengths of pipelines and `xargs`.
You should *usually* be hoping that the spawned xargs child
will process a batch of input lines,
so we can amortize cost of spawning across them.
But here we a tiny trivial amount of processing,
discard the process, and spawn a `printf` child
to again do trivial processing.

Prefer a single script for this whole pipeline.
The sed / sh / printf could easily be accomplished
within a python (or perl) `for` loop.
Make a call to
[crc32](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) or
[adler32](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.adler32),
or perhaps emit prefix nybbles from one of the
[crypto hashes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.sha224).

Comment: the second part of the line being split has spaces in it, and thus I have to use a null delimiter and replace newlines with it, or xargs will treat spaces and newlines as delimiters. so, I have `thing foo whatever\n` and without `-0` xargs will treat that as 3 tokens. So, if I have `thing foo whatever\0 | xargs -0` then xargs properly parses this

Comment: `sh -e -c` tells it to exit error the shell on and command error. This doesn't include pipefail